# Update client state with firestore triggers

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding a chat app with firebase. I made the backend with **firestore** and cloud functions, and I am doing the frontend with react and redux.

Now, I need to update the redux state whenever someone writes a new message in the firestore, so I need something in the frontend that looks at changes in the firestore and than updates the client state based on the changes.

Firestore triggers seem perfect for this purpose.

My question is: Is possible to write firestore triggers or similar in the frontend? Otherwise, is there an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ciao, have you tried with web socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to write firestore triggers or similar in the frontend?

Yes, you need to use the `onSnapshot()` methods, which you can use on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) or on a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) or even on a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onsnapshot).

Have also a look at this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).